# What is meant by a single-threaded kernel?

Tags: operating-systems, os-kernel

I was looking at [this course](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/training/course/oopnclkern.html) but I cannot seem to understand what is meant by the term *"single-threaded kernel"*.

Does it mean that:

1. only a single kernel thread is made available by the OS?
2. only a single kernel thread can be executed at one time?

or is there some other interpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will be adding to [nir shahar](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/121717/nir-shahar)'s answer.

A single-threaded kernel is essentially a kernel that processes only one thread at a time. We can have multiple kernel threads, but only one can get executed at any given point in time. This can be achieved by some scheduling procedure on the kernel threads.

But is this the same thing as having only one kernel thread (and using the *many-to-one* model) as even multiple threads have to be executed sequentially?

**NO!** A blocking call made on a *many-to-one* model blocks all other processes mapped to that kernel thread. Having a *one-to-one* model will allow for other processes to run even if one process executes a blocking call.

This does come at a cost. The overheads of creating and managing multiple kernel threads are somewhat expensive, but it all depends on your usage.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of the differences :)

Answer (score 1):

It literally means that the kernel runs only on one core.

Different threads can be run on multiple cpu cores, and thus a single-threaded kernel is a kernel that runs only in one core

Comment: So does this mean that I have only 1 kernel thread as in the Many-to-One model? Or is it that I have multiple kernel threads on a single core and I can have the One-to-One model as well?

Comment: Just as a side comment, there are solutions for multiple threads running on different cores, however those solutions are way more complicated that single threaded kernels

Comment: There is a difference in running processes sequentially on a single thread, and mapping them to their individual kernel threads and running the threads (in some order). When a system blocking call is made, the *One-to-One* model will allow for the other threads to run.

Comment: I have posted my own answer explaining this, I hope that clears things up.